# not able to reconfigure gitlab-ee getting below error

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ee

libsepol.context_from_record: type gitlab_shell_t is not defined (No such file or directory).
libsepol.context_from_record: could not create context structure (Invalid argument).
libsemanage.validate_handler: invalid context system_u:object_r:gitlab_shell_t:s0 specified for /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh(/.*)? [all files] (Invalid argument).
libsemanage.dbase_llist_iterate: could not iterate over records (Invalid argument).
semodule:  Failed!